# Generic typescript function to validate that the key of an object is a string

Tags: typescript

Here is the function I'd like to write, and I cannot quite get the generic to work.

As you can see - I'd like to return that T[K] is definitely a string - the point is to be able to use it

```js
a = {key: "unknown type"};

if (!validateRequiredStringKey(a, "key")) {
    return
}
// Here we should know that a.key is a string

funcThatTakesAString(a.key);
```

```js
export const validateRequiredStringKey = <
  T,
  K extends keyof T & (string | number)
>(
  obj: T,
  key: K
): obj is T & { [K]: string } => {
  const v = obj[key];

  if (!(typeof v === "string")) {
    throw new ValidationError(`${key} is not a string`);
  }
  if (v === "") {
    throw new ValidationError(`${key} is empty`);
  }
  return true;
};
```

The errors from `tsc` are

```
src/domain/validations/utils.ts:12:17 - error TS1170: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

12 ): obj is T & { [K]: string } => {
                   ~~~

src/domain/validations/utils.ts:12:18 - error TS2693: 'K' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

12 ): obj is T & { [K]: string } => {
```

Comment: The syntax is `{[k in K]: string}` for a mapped type, or you can write `Record<K, string>` for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't thoroughly checked the definition of `validateRequiredStringKey`, but you can make it work by replacing `{ [K]: string }` with `{[Key in K]: string}`, or just `Record<K, string>`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wG4EMA2BLAEyxmACVgBHAVzymAIGUYo9kBzAaWAE84BeOAB4AUHDgAVADSi4HOKBLICqOAGseEAGYS4AMjgAKdC3ZwAPnGRUAtgCNgUAJTCAfAZkRbAKwBcE6WLq3H4cwo5+nl5weCoG4npw5EhQBIIcknDGrGwujvwucADeMkhomPxwkQDaQQC6ANzCMnjaBgCEBjDcYMBacBj8fAIARFnsw455xWJiMAAWUBAA7pbAKwCiUItQBgAGACSFQQC+0SrIEPBYmczZu46NYsfNrQNDIxNFMrMLy6sbW2ge0OJzO8msYC690ecGeYjoMCoUGQcGYVGAjWOjWEpXQcE0VGQCHEc2I4iw6lQAEEmCY2BUjH4xmw8nwCoVnjiUHiSHiBAYsH4jjw-ITVBclshjqz2SVufAxSiBFgAHRBGEAeg1MzgAD0APwyAlEklkinAam07ICtU8B5wLX4rB4HCoJpiFqGNrYfBEEjkai0ehW9hcbgCjLDIITKbfGYIpHIGFwxDym5QCqq9UyR0zA1GwnE0kwcmUmm3dg2oL2x2oKgIBDAehu55AA)